# How do I get mu Ubuntu server to boot?

Tags: boot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmuzO.jpg

I have had my ubuntu server 18.04.2 a few weeks running fine.
Yesterday I found it stuck at boot and I can’t seem to get it up again.

I can boot to recovery, but I’m not sure what to look for. Any ideas?

Edit: I uninstalled the nvidia drivers and got it to boot but now the network is down and I cant seem to start it.

Comment: Ok - could well be be you have a hardware failure or something - like a power outage caused the server to restart. Have a look at this web page - though a little old - offers a lot of good things to check.
```https://www.techradar.com/how-to/computing/how-to-boot-repair-ubuntu-1315203```
A good place to start

Comment: Thanks, it was the nvidia drivers that stalled the boot but now I can’t get the network to work!

Comment: Ok - have you checked the harddisks for corruption as suggested? If so - can you see any of the lights on the Ethernet adapter and switch flashing at all? What do you see if you type ```ifconfig``` on the command line? Has an IP address been assigned to the network adapter? Do you use DHCP or Static IP adddress assignment? Without knowing your layout - it could be a lot of things causing the lack of network connection.

Comment: The SSD has been checked: btrfs check and scrub. No errors.

Comment: I added 10 entries of "enp6s[0-10]: dhcp4: true" in the netplan config and removed what was there before. It started working again after that, don't ask me why that conf hasn't been touched in months... What is bugging me now is that it waits for something at boot but the text is cut off, so I don't know what?

Comment: If you have a look at the ```dmesg``` messages you can follow what happens while the machine was loading. There are also tools you can install to graph the boot process so you can see what is taking the time. Google is your friend there. I would suspect without seeing any detail that it's a driver waiting to do some task and timing out. As you have been having network issues it could be a DNS/resolver config setting.